# React Native Fetch Api Unable to Set Cookie Header

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, fetch-api

I am developing a react native app and php rest service as backend.

When user login i echo user and session id info as `$response` array with `json_encode()` function.

`$response['user']` stores user info.
`$response['sessid']` stores session id.

In Postman i can set a Header as Cookie and as value i use sessionid. It works perfectly. But in fetch api i can't set Cookie header.

Here is my code:

```
const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('sessid');
console.log("value" + value)
var url = 'http://192.168.1.27/zuper/test.php';
fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET', 
  headers:{
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Cookie' : value
  }
}).then(  (response) => {
  console.warn(response)
 })
```

This is value of value variable : `0d580f8b8e1e1ead1ce038cb12289a57`

Response for this fetch comes with a php error which says

> user is not defined

from line `$_SESSION['user']['name']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Cookie is listed amoung the [forbidden header names](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-header-name):

> These are forbidden so the user agent remains in full control over them.

If you want to send a Cookie in an HTTP request, then you must make a prior HTTP request to the same origin that uses a `Set-Cookie` response header to set it.