# How to get `Set-Cookie`, store it, and send it in React Native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, cookies

## Reference

1. ["credentials: include"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159138/react-native-get-cookies) to send the cookies with HttpOnly, "omit" to prevent sending the cookie with HttpOnly.
2. [You can't add Cookie's key to the Request Headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51855090/react-native-fetch-api-unable-to-set-cookie-header)

I am not sure whether React Native stores the cookie, I could not see it using React Native Debugger `Application > Cookies` always return empty.

## TL:DR

My goal is to mimic browser behaviors for cookies, which are:

1. Get `Set-Cookie` key from the response headers and store it as cookies, especially the one with HttpOnly. I also wish to store it in the AsyncStorage to persist the cookies.
   [The MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

   ```
   fetch("http://localhost:8080", {
     method: "GET",
     credentials: "include",
   }).then(response => console.log(response.headers)); // response.headers does not contain the `Set-Cookie`.
   ```
2. Send the cookies value in Request Headers in the `Cookie` key.

   The current solution I found is, but I do not have the evidence to prove it yet:

   ```
   fetch("http://localhost:8080", {
     method: "GET",
     credentials: "include",
   });
   ```
3. See the `Cookies` with React Native Debugger in `Application > Cookies`.

I tried to use React Native Fetch API

```
fetch("http://localhost:8080", {
  method: "GET",
  credentials: "include",
});
```

But I could not get the `Set-Cookie` from the Response Headers. With React Native Debugger in `Network > /`, the `Set-Cookie` keys are always not present in the Response Headers, while if I use the Browser, I can see the `Set-Cookie` in the Response Headers.